# Setup auto build after push on TeamCity

Tags: github, teamcity

I have GitHub repo and TeamCity 2018.2.1. 
I have already setup periodic check of git in the TeamCity (every 30 sec). But it's not good solution for me. 
I want an automatic build as soon as someone does a push.

As I understand, I need to setup webhooks on GitHub. I have already done this and the GitHub sends me such requests:

```
"POST /webhooks/endpoint.html HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "GitHub-Hookshot/6031d40" "192.30.252.38"
```

But TeamCity does not understand them at all.
In the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Integrating+TeamCity+with+VCS+Hosting+Services#IntegratingTeamCitywithVCSHostingServices-CreatingEntitiesfromURLinTeamCity) I did not find anything related to the settings for getting webhooks.

Has anyone set this up? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.
You need to install this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9179-github-commit-hooks

After installation in the action menu of project settings you can find "Install GitHub Webhook".